# Does sleeping an average of 11 hours or more raise one's risk of brain-related disorders?

Tags: medical-science, natural-remedies, sleep, cognitive-fitness, psychiatry

I am familiar with the effects of sleep deprivation and some of the [harmful effects of oversleeping](http://www.webmd.com/sleep-disorders/guide/physical-side-effects-oversleeping). However, I have also heard more than once that sleeping more than 10 hours on average, even for a non-sedentary person, can lower overall brain alertness and acuity. In addition, I have heard that it can cause the premature onset of Alzheimer's disease and other brain-related diseases.

This is something entirely unfamiliar to me and I was wondering: Is this supported by scientific evidence?

Comment: Wouldn't over sleeping perhaps be a symptom of other issues, such as depression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**NO**.There has been no research which points to over sleeping leading to brain disorders.

> Conversely, certain brain disorders
>   [can](http://www.buzzle.com/articles/causes-of-sleeping-too-much.html) cause oversleeping.

Oversleeping has been [shown](http://www.webmd.com/sleep-disorders/guide/physical-side-effects-oversleeping) to cause diabetics, obesity and other health problems but **not** any serious brain disorders.

The [claim](http://topnews.net.nz/content/2430-over-sleeping-including-afternoon-naps-can-increase-alzheimer-risk) that long sleeps and after noon naps may *lead to Alzheimer's disease* could in fact be due to the *reverse correlation*, i.e people who are prone to develop Alzheimer's disease in future are over-sleepers, probably due to other brain related issues (**not** the *other way*)