# Does oversleeping lead to reduced alertness?

Tags: sleep

There are several studies ([Example 1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12683469), [Example 2](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12603781)) about the effect of sleep deprivation on alertness and cognitive performance.

Are there any studies investigating the opposite - The effect of too much sleep on alertness, also known as the [Rip Van Winkle Effect](http://www.answers.com/topic/rip-van-winkle-effect)?

With "alertness" I mean two factors:

1. subjective mental alertness as reported by test subjects and,
2. objectively measured cognitive performance.

I am *not* talking about any health consequences, either long-term or short-term. There is already another question covering that:

- [Does sleeping an average of 11 hours or more raise one's risk of brain-related disorders?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2414/does-sleeping-an-average-of-11-hours-or-more-raise-ones-risk-of-brain-related-d)

Comment: There is certainly a lot of anecdotal evidence for this - i feel much more sleepy if I over-sleep! Interested to hear of any studies...

Comment: Apparently not, [according to Einstein](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7705/did-albert-einstein-sleep-10-11-hours-daily).

Comment: Do you have a notable claim that it does?

Comment: My understanding, from reading and asking doctors about sleep apnea, is that there is no such thing as oversleeping. It does take you longer to wake to full alertness after a deep sleep than after a 20 minute nap. But in general, if you are getting regular, adequate sleep and do not wake up feeling refreshed and ready to start the day, then you likely have a sleep issue (e.g., sleep apnea).